# Orthonormal List In Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

guys say we have a orthonormal list say ${O_n}_{n\in A}$ that is an orthonormal list in a Hilbert Space $X$. Is it true that the list is complete if and only if

$<a,b>= \sum_{n \in A} <a,O_n><y,u_n>$ For some $a,b \in X$

I think this is true but when we are working with the Reals.

Comment: What is $u_n$?${} $